# how to reverse paring google map address with lat,long in json format?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

i know how to do reverse paring google map with lac, ci params in a json format, but i can
not find the way like this do a parse with lat, long params, is it not possible?
thanks advance.

Comment: you want to get address using lat,long in Json format?

Comment: actually yes, or any good idea?

Comment: did you see this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 0):

Try [The Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: It should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with the `google-maps` keyword, you can also the Geocoding API directly from within Google Maps (example is for Gmaps API V3):

```
    gmaps.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: gmaps.map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
            });

            marker.setTitle(address);

            gmaps.bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
            gmaps.map.fitBounds(gmaps.bounds);

            if(typeof(callback) === 'function') {
                callback(marker);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
```

This snippet will fetch the address' geometry location, and plots it in the map (which lives in gmaps.map). It'll also make sure that all markers fit within the bounds of the map.